# Javascript indexOf is not a function when using integer

Tags: javascript

I have following array (just a quick example):

```
books:[
            {id: 1, isbn: '0226020452', title: 'The Bridge on the Drina', author: 'Ivo Andrić',
            description: '',
                added: '2017-07-29'
            },
            {id: 2, isbn: '9781628724189', title: 'Bosnian Chronicle: A Novel', author: 'Ivo Andrić',
                description: '',
                added: '2017-07-29'
            },
            {id: 3, isbn: '9781856100229', title: 'Damned Yard and Other Stories', author: 'Ivo Andrić',
                description: '',
                added: '2017-07-29'
            },
```

When I try to perform following function I get this error **Uncaught TypeError: book.id.indexOf is not a function**:

```
updateBook: function (state, updateBook) {

    let foundBook = state.books.filter((book) => {
            return book.id.indexOf(parseInt(updateBook.id, 10)) >= 0;
    })

    console.log(foundBook);

    Object.assign(state.book[foundBook], updateBook);
   }
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `id` is a number, not an array or string ...?

Comment: I think you need `==` i.e. `book.id  == parseInt(updateBook.id, 10)` and also note `filter()` will return you an array

Comment: @NinaScholz - the id is an integer.

Comment: @Sasha You've misunderstood the use of `indexOf`, an integer doesn't have the said property.

Comment: @NinaScholz is correct, See [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for getting an index of an array.

```
let index = state.books.findIndex(book => book.id === updateBook.id);

console.log(foundBook);
if (index !== -1) {
    // update existing book
    Object.assign(state.book[index], updateBook);
} else {
    // insert new book
}
```